# how do i assigne out put of command as variable

Tags: bash, scripting

Hi i am very new to scripting. please My apologizes if i am pointing in wrong way.

I am trying to develop a script which take the backup of given path. Below is my script.
The problem I facing is that I am trying to assign a variable "s" to an command "mkdir" and it do not work. Please help me,how i can correct this syntax?

```
#!/bin/bash
# to back up the given folder "

i="`date | awk '{ print $1$2$4}'`"
echo " please enter the full path of folder you want to back up"
read foldern

echo " $foldern is of `du -sh $foldern`. Do you want to back up this folder"
echo "yes / no"
read ans

if [ $ans = yes ]
 then
  echo " enter the back up folder name"
  read  bpn
  s=$(mkdir $bpn$i)   # here I am trying to assign a variable "s" for out put of mkdir but dosent work Please help me #
echo $s
 cp -R  "$foldern"  "$s"
 else
   echo "no back up is taken"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir` does not create an output or print the directory it has created. Manually create the string instead:

```
s=$bpn$i
mkdir -- "$s"
echo "$s"
```

`--` is an optional option-argument separator so files beginning with `-` is not misinterpreted as a bad option to `mkdir`.

Adding `-p` can also be helpful if you don't want `mkdir` to show an error if the directory already exists.

```
mkdir -p -- "$s"
```

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

# To back up the given folder.

date=$(date | awk '{ print $1$2$4}')  ## Consider date=$(date '+%F-%T')

read -p "Please enter the full path of folder you want to back up: " folder_name

size=$(du -sh "$folder_name")
read -p "$folder_name is of $size. Do you want to back up this folder (Yes/No)? "

if [[ $ans == [yY][eE][sS] ]]; then
    read -p "Enter the back up folder name: " backup_name
    backup_name+=$date
    echo "$backup_name"
    mkdir -p "$backup_name" && cp -R "$folder_name" "$backup_name"
else
    echo "No back up is taken."
fi
```

Comment: then how do i copy given folder to created folder

Comment: @user3933193 Doesn't `cp` do that? Btw, please try my suggestion. If it works, you can compare it to your own script.

Comment: @user3933193 Welcome. Please accept the answer if it's already best enough for you. Just click the check mark next to it.

Comment: your answer is working for me. This is my first post and i want to rate your answer but i am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user3933193 There's a check mark or tick mark on the upper left part of my answer. You just have to click it. It should turn green after.

Comment: You did it. Thank you :)

Comment: sorry to disturb you again. Just Quarries to know how this command is adding date to folder name

Comment: It appends the value of `$date` to `backup_name`. It's a feature of bash.

Comment: From `bash`: *When applied to a string-valued variable, value is expanded and appended to the variable’s value.* See [Shell Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters).